# Optimize multiple join same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: `student`, `address`.

address includes `id` and `location`
student includes `id`, `name`, `roommate_id`, `location_id`.

I need to find student's info with student location and roommate location.
I have used the query:

```
SELECT
student.name as name, stulocation.location as address,
roommate.name as roommate_name, rmatelocation.location as roommate_address
FROM student
LEFT JOIN student as roommate ON student.roommate_id = roommate.id
LEFT JOIN location as stulocation ON student.location_id = stulocation.id
LEFT JOIN location as rmatelocation ON roommate.location_id = rmatelocation .id
```

I have joined the same table `location` twice. Is there any better solution to it, instead of querying same table 2 time?

Comment: Your query is syntactically wrong, but joining 2 copies of student to 2 copies of location is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Show tables structures as CREATE TABLE scripts, not as verbal description. Show some sample data as INSERT INTO scripts (2-3 rooms 2-3 students each is enough). Show desired output for this data.